# Application Transaction + C# + more than one operation

Tags: c#, scope, transactions

I would Like to ask you, if there is a way to set some operations into transaction.
I have problem such like this:

1) Generate File from data from database
2) Encrypt it
3) Send to server

I would like do it in one transaction. Any failured step 1-3 should cause the cancelling transaction.

Best regards,

Comment: Why does this need to be in a transaction?  You're not updating any data (from what you've said), so there is nothing to rollback...

Comment: I need to be sure, that file which has been generated from data from DB, was created on the disk, encrypted sucessfully and then sended to the server.

Comment: Could you explain what you expect to happen if the transaction fails i.e. what state you expect to be rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need a transaction for this as you only update the database in your last step. Any failure up to that point does not affect any other data from what you describe in your post.

Update: You may want to look at [Volatile Resource Managers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163688.aspx)

Comment: I update database after first step. Second and third step, doesn't use a database

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Check out **TransactionScope** and **MSDTC**.

Answer (score 0):

As curious_geek stated it can be achived with a TransactionScope. But it can be tricky to work with transactions, especially when you want to do more than one type of operation per transaction.

Are you even sure that you need a transaction? Cant you just delete the file again if step 2 or 3 fails?